# C++ - Cannot remove the element from the Queue

Tags: c++, data-structures, fifo

I'm trying to remove the first element of the Queue but, this does not seem to work. Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int front = -1;
int rear = -1;
int i = 0;
const int size = 4;
int Q[size];

bool isEmpty(){
    return front == -1 && rear == -1;
}
bool isFull(){
    return rear == size - 1;
}
void Enqueue(int x){
    if(isFull()){
        cout << "The Queue is full." <<endl;
    }
    else if(isEmpty()){
        front++;
        rear++;
    }
    else{
        rear++;
    }
    Q[rear] = x;
}
void Dequeue(){
    if(isEmpty()){
        cout << "The Queue is empty." << endl;
    }
    else if(front == rear){
        front = -1;
        rear = -1;
    }
    else{
        front++;
    }
}
void display(){
    cout << "The Queue is: " << endl;
    for(i = 0; i <= rear; i++){
        cout << Q[i] << endl;   
    }
}

int main(){
    Enqueue(1);
    Enqueue(2);
    display();
    Dequeue();
    display();
    return 0;
}
```

This `Dequeue()` function should remove the element at `front` but, it is not doing so. This is the output i'm getting from the above code:

```
The Queue is:
1
2
The Queue is:
1
2
```

Instead of :

```
The Queue is:
1
2
The Queue is:
2
```

I tried some other solutions, but with no luck. I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: A sheet of paper and a debugger will make you find the problem in far less time than it took to write the question! Put a column for each variable (front, rear, i, x) and for each slot in the array. Then trace the code and write each value on a line. At some point, you will see a mismatch between what you expect and what you got. By the way, using `-1` as an value to tell it is empty only complicate code! Difference between `rear` and `front` should be the number of items. And finally, your queue won't work as expected if it does not become empty each time it get full...

Comment: Will certainly keep this in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to start at `front` in `display`. It should look like this instead:

```
void display(){
    cout << "The Queue is: " << endl;
    for(int i = front; i <= rear; ++i) {
        cout << Q[i] << endl;   
    }
}
```

Note: This function will behave badly (i.e. produce undefined behaviour) when the queue is empty. You can fix this, by starting with `int i = std::max(0, front);` or special case the empty case.

Another approach would be to point the `rear` to the element past the last element. The range `front, rear` then is empty for `front == rear` and the number of elements in the range is simply `rear - front`. This is a common paradigm in C++, see `begin` and `end` of any standard container, e.g. `std::vector`.